# Obj-c pointer to C++ has changed

Tags: c++, objective-c, pointers

I have a C++ class FooCpp, a C++ Interface IFOO and a Obj-c class FooObjC, on IFOO i have:

```
public:
    virtual ~IFOO() {};
    virtual void seePointer(FooCpp* p);
```

on FooCpp I have:

on .h

```
class FooCpp : virtual public IFOO {
public:
    virtual ~FooCpp() {};
    void seePointer(FooCpp* p);
}
```

and .cpp

```
void FooCpp::seePointer(IFOO* p){
    printf("%p\n",p);
}
```

and on FooObjC I call it:

```
FooCpp *foo = new FooCpp();
FooCpp *f = new FooCpp();
printf("%p\n",f);
foo->seePointer(f);
```

and when I this I'm getting the follow log:

```
0x848f520
0x61630002
```

why the point address was changed? because this i getting a error on my program, somebody knows why this and how to fix it?

Comment: Works for me.  When I implement your code I get: `0x100109f30
0x100109f30`.  I can upload the project somewhere if you like.  Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Here is my working project: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18450868/CppTest.zip

Comment: @trojanfoe I'll try using a FooObjC.mm instead of FooObjC.m maybe be this because I'm using .cpp and .m and not .cpp and .mm

Comment: I don't understand how it compiles when using `.m`? (unless you've told Xcode to treat the file as Objective-C++).

Comment: @trojanfoe it's :), and not did effect, the problem may lie deeper, in fact these classes are interfaces, can this be related?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand?  It's what?

Comment: @trojanfoe my project is to IOS. I'll add details on question.

Comment: I doubt the fact it's iOS would matter (at least it shouldn't matter).

Comment: @trojanfoe I added details. I hope you can emulate the error.

Comment: No same behaviour, but then I just made `class IFOO
{
    int x;
};`, not knowing how else to define it.  Is `seePointer()` a `virtual` method by any chance?

Comment: @trojanfoe a yes it is a virtual I'll fix on the question. but here I really getting this error. :(

Comment: I've fixed my code to use virtual `seePointer()` and still no change.  I've updated the project on Dropbox: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18450868/CppTest.zip

Comment: Hey wait a moment... that won't compile, because the signature for the `FooCpp::setPointer` definition doesn't match any member function declared in the class.

Answer (score 0):

It's not unusual for a base subobject to have a different address than the complete object, especially when virtual inheritance is involved.

However, the difference between the two pointers should be small (less than `sizeof (FooCpp)`.

Either you've got some sort of corruption (perhaps mismatched calling conventions) or else Objective-C++ is doing something really weird, like tearoff proxy objects.